# how to find unique words in two strings?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have two separate strings:

```
string s1 = "Hello welcome to the world of C sharp";

String s2 = "Hello world welcome to the world of C";
```

Now I want to fetch the unique words in the two strings like `{sharp}`.

Also I want to find the similar words in the same program like `{Hello, welcome, to, the , world of, C}`.

I am not able to proceed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

In C#, you can use:

```
string[] words1 = s1.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] words2 = s2.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Retrieve words that only exist in one list
var unique = words1.Except(words2).Concat(words2.Except(words1)); 

// Retrieve all "similar words" - exist in either list
var matches = words1.Intersect(words2);
```

Comment: No need for the split option here.

Comment: @oldrinb Not in this exact example, but as a general purpose rule, if tokenizing a "sentence" into "words" (which *seemed* to be the OP's goal), it's a good idea to include.  I included it since removing it could lead to `string.Empty` being included in results when used with general purpose data if it were left out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `Split()` and `Except()`:

```
        string s1 = "Hello welcome to the world of C sharp";

        string s2 = "Hello world welcome to the world of C";

        var s1Words = s1.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var s2Words = s2.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var s1Only = s1Words.Except(s2Words);
        var s2Only = s2Words.Except(s1Words);

        Console.WriteLine("The unique words in S1 are: " + string.Join(",", s1Only));
        Console.WriteLine("The unique words in S2 are: " + string.Join(",", s2Only));
```

If you need them in the same list, you can use `Concat()`:

```
var allUniqueWords = s1Only.Concat(s2Only);
```

You can also find the words that are the same using `Intersect()`:

```
var sameWords = s1Words.Intersect(s2Words);
```

The set operations in LINQ are great for these type of things.  There's also a `Union()` that would give you a distinct list of all words from both, for example:

```
var allWords = s1Words.Union(s2Words);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am honestly not exactly sure what you're going for, but here's a few possible answers:

Get words that only exist in one string or the other:

```
using System.Linq;
...
string s1 ="Hello welcome to the world of C sharp";
string s2 = "Hello world welcome to the world of C"; 
List<string> s1List = (s1 + " " + s2)
            .Split(' ')
            .Where(s=> (!s2.Split(' ').Contains(s) || !s1.Split(' ').Contains(s)))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

Get all unique words:

```
using System.Linq;
...
string s1 ="Hello welcome to the world of C sharp";
string s2 = "Hello world welcome to the world of C"; 

 List<string> s1List = (s1 + " " + s2).Split(' ').Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some of the nice set operations provided by the Framework:

```
string s1 ="Hello welcome to the world of C sharp";
string s2 = "Hello world welcome to the world of C";

string[] words1 = s1.Split(' ');
string[] words2 = s2.Split(' ');

var s1UniqueWords = words1.Except(words2);
var s2UniqueWords = words2.Except(words1);

var sharedWords = words1.Intersect(words2);
```

For more information on the various set operations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> UniqueWords(string[] setsOfWords)
{
    List<string> words = new List<string>();
    foreach (var setOfWords in setsOfWords)
    {
        words.AddRange(setOfWords.Split(new char[] { ' ' }));
    }
    return words.Distinct().ToList();            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++.  Assumes you have some sort of StringTokenizer class that splits the string:

```
string s1 ="Hello welcome to the world of C sharp";

string s2 = "Hello world welcome to the world of C";

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    stringTokenizer lStrToken1(s1);
    stringTokenizer lStrToken2(s2);

    vector<string> lVS1 = lStrToken1.getTokens();
    vector<string> lVS2 = lStrToken2.getTokens();

sort( lVS1.begin(), lVS1.end() );
sort( lVS2.begin(), lVS2.end() );
vector<string> lDiff;

set_difference( lVS1.begin(), lVS1.end(), lVS2.begin(), lVS2.end(), 
        inserter( lDiff, lDiff.end() ) );

vector<string>::iterator lIter = lDiff.begin();
for ( ; lIter != lDiff.end(); ++lIter ) {
cout << *lIter << endl;
}

cout << endl;
```

}